# What is wrong with my function and main method?

Tags: c, function, return, printf, getline

I am writing a C program with 2 functions and a main. The first function reads & stores the character (more description is included in the comment below). I'm not sure if I terminated the string right(with the 0)??
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20


/* reads a line from the keyboard and stores the characters in the array str.
If the user enters more than max characters, it returns -1. Function should terminate             
the char array with a NULL (or 0) */

int getline(char str[], int max){
    char c, i;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        str[i] = c;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    str[i] = '\0';

    if (i < MAX)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}

/* calculates and returns  the length of the array passed to it */
int strlen(char str[]){
    int i = 0;

    while(str[i] != NULL)
        i++;

    return i;
}


main(){
    char str[MAX];
    printf("Please Enter a String less than 20 characters:\n");

    if((getline(str, MAX)) == 0)
        printf("Length of ‘%s’ = %d", str, (strlen(str)));
    else
        printf("You Entered more than 20 Characters!");
}
```

Comment: `str[i] != NULL` might happen to work, but it's incorrect. `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. You want `str[i] != '\0'`

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `i` to 0 in your `getline()`.

On the other hand, the 2nd parameter of `getline()` is `max`. But you only refered to `MAX` in the function. Luckily, since the only place calling `getline()` use `MAX` as the 2nd parameter, you don't observe any difference. Furthermore, to avoid writing out of array boundary, you should check for array index *inside* the loop instead of *after* the loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean about MAX? Wouldn't it repeatedly check for it inside the loop then?

Comment: Yes, but you _should_ check it repeatedly. Otherwise, when you found `i >= MAX` after the loop, you've already write over the array boundary.

Comment: is that why when I type more than 20 characters the program crashes?

Comment: & is the default in C for a variable not automatically 0?

Comment: Yes. That's why your program crashes instead of issuing error message elegantly when you type more than 20 characters; static variables and global variables are automatically initialized to 0, but local variables are not implicitly initialized.

Comment: You could return -1 inside the loop whenever i went beyond the boundary. Then you could return 0 without checking after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `getline(char str[], int max)`

You have not initialized the local variable, `i` !

Comment: so in C the default for a variable is not automatically 0?

Comment: Only global and static are initialized to `0`. Locals contain garbage value and require initialization.